# How do you get the display settings of a field on a particular content type/display

Tags: entities, theming, database

I'm looking to preprocess a field.

The field type I'm wanting to preprocess is an entity reference field.

I need to know what view mode has been selected on the display settings for this field (see screenshot below).

[image: Field display settings]

This information is not made available in the $variables variable passed into preprocess_field.

So how can I get this load this information? I have tried looking for some Drupal-specific functions that would return these settings but haven't found anything that works.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`field_info_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7)

> Returns an array of instance data for a specific field and bundle

Example usage:

```
$info = field_info_instance('node', 'field_foo', 'article');
$display_settings = $info['display'];
```

`$display_settings` will be an array of display settings keyed by the view modes that are customisable for that content type and bundle.